# querySelectorAll On Multiple Classes Not Working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display multiple clocks on the same page. However, querySelectorAll doesn't seem to be doing it. I'm using modern browsers (have tested in Chrome and Safari). What am I doing wrong?

JS Code:

```
/*global document, window */
function checkTime(i) {
    'use strict';
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
function a() {
    'use strict';
    var oct = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
        octtime,
        oct1,
        oct2,
        oct3,
        oct4,
        oct5,
        oct6,
        octvalue,
        point = ".",
        now = new Date(),
        hours = now.getHours(),
        minutes = now.getMinutes(),
        seconds = now.getSeconds(),
        h = checkTime(hours),
        m = checkTime(minutes),
        s = checkTime(seconds),
        totsecs = [hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds + (now.getTime() % 1000) / 1000];
    octtime = Math.floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144));
    oct1 = Math.floor(octtime / 32768);
    octtime -= 32768 * oct1;
    oct2 = Math.floor(octtime / 4096);
    octtime -= 4096 * oct2;
    oct3 = Math.floor(octtime / 512);
    octtime -= 512 * oct3;
    oct4 = Math.floor(octtime / 64);
    octtime -= 64 * oct4;
    oct5 = Math.floor(octtime / 8);
    octtime -= 8 * oct5;
    oct6 = octtime;
    octvalue = point + oct[oct1] + oct[oct2] + oct[oct3] + oct[oct4] + oct[oct5] + oct[oct6];
    document.querySelectorAll(".c").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.querySelectorAll(".d").innerHTML = octvalue;
    window.setTimeout(a);
}
window.onload = a;
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="a">
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Regular Time</b>
<td><b>Octal Time</b>
<tr>
<td class="c">JS problem
<td class="d">JS problem
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div class="a">
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Regular Time</b>
<td><b>Octal Time</b>
<tr>
<td class="c">JS problem
<td class="d">JS problem
</table>
</div>
<script src="/1.js"></script>
```

Test page: http://www.gloryhood.com/ztest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not a single node element, so you need to iterate and set the value

```
function setHtmlForByClass(clazz, html) {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.' + clazz)
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].innerHTML = html;
    }
}
setHtmlForByClass('c', h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
setHtmlForByClass('d', octvalue);
```